# Expenses (Singular or Plural)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I wonder whether the word expenses  is normally singular or plural in the following sense:

> - Hey Brian, please keep track of all (**expense / expenses**) you make so that we can settle (**it / them**) later.

As you can see, the word "[expense](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/expense)" can be either countable or uncountable and I have no idea in what form it should be used here to be natural-sounding?
The problem is that depending the form of the word "expense(s), the following pronoun should be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plural:

1. Please keep track of **all expenses**.
2. Please keep track of **these expenses**.
3. Please keep track of **two expenses**.

Singular:

1. Please keep track of **every expense**.
2. Please keep track of **this expense**.
3. Please keep track of **one expense**.

In most cases (there are some exceptions—but not when it comes to this word), if it doesn't have an *s* it's singular, and if it does have an *s* it's plural.

In this sense, *expense* is always countable.

---

In referring to the citation you give, it's a completely different sense of *expense* that is an uncountable noun:

> At the *expense* of somebody.

Even though the word is spelled identically, its meaning is different, and, in this sense, uncountable. You have to look at the context.

In order to use this sense in a countable way, you would have to count something slightly different:

> Please keep track of the **times** it was done at somebody else's *expense*.

---

Incidentally, because this particular sense of *expense* is uncountable, the following makes very little sense:

> ✘ At the *expenses* of somebody.

That should not be confused with the other sense of the word that is countable:

> ✔ Count the *expenses* that **belong** to somebody.

This can be confusing, but it's the phrase *at the expense of* (or *at my/your/his/her/their/our expense*) that triggers this specific uncountable meaning of *expense*.

Comment: Then I should say: "Please keep track of all expense**s** you make so that we can settle **them** later." Right Jason? Also, please let me know if using the definite article "the" prior to "expenses" sounds idiomatic or it is superfluous?

Comment: Yes, recurring payments are _expenses - expense_ would be the cost of a single purchase, or the metaphorical usage. I would say _the_ was optional.